# JQuery not defined and not loading in application.js in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed in a local machine one RoR app which runs in production. The app works fine in production and on other local machines, but I have one that doesn't load jquery properly.

The app works with Rails 3.1.0 and Ruby 1.9.3-p547. The app use apache tomcat 6 with Solr too. The OS is Ubuntu 15.10.

The problem is that application.js.erb apparently doesn't compile well because when I inspect the code in DevTools it doesn't compile the parts with //=. And the devTools console says me that JQuery it's not defined.

My **Gemfile**

```
    # encoding: utf-8
source 'http://rubygems.org'

if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
gem 'rack', '1.3.6'


# Gems for database and indexing data
gem 'pg'

gem 'sunspot_rails','2.0.0'
gem 'sunspot_solr', '2.0.0'

gem 'redis'
gem 'redis-namespace'
gem 'impressionist', '1.3.1'

# Gems for behaviors 
gem 'acts_as_tree', '1.2.0'
gem "eventmachine", '1.0.9.1'


gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.1'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'uglifier'
end


# Gems for presentation

gem 'gon', "4.1.1"              # Data to your js files (https://github.com/gazay/gon)
gem 'friendly_id'               # "Swiss Army bulldozer" of slugging and permalink plugins (http://github.com/norman/friendly_id)
gem 'jquery-rails', "1.0.19"    # jQuery and the jQuery-ujs driver (http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails)
gem 'draper', '0.12'            # Draper adds a nicely-separated object-oriented layer of presentation logic (http://github.com/drapergem/draper)
gem 'mustache', "0.99.5"        # Mustache is a framework-agnostic way to render logic-free views (http://github.com/defunkt/mustache)
gem "paperclip", "2.7.0"        # Easy upload management for ActiveRecord (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)
gem "progress_bar"              # Give people feedback about long-running tasks (http://www.github.com/paul/progress_bar)
gem "js-routes", "0.7.5"        # Generates javascript file that defines all Rails named routes as javascript helpers (https://github.com/railsware/js-routes)
gem "useragent"                 # Ruby library that parses and compares HTTP User Agents.
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', "~> 3.0.0"

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano', "2.12.0"
gem 'rvm-capistrano', "1.2.7",  require: false

# Mail sending
gem "mail"                      # Internet library for Ruby that is designed to handle emails generation (https://github.com/mikel/mail)
gem "roadie", '~> 2.4'                    # Roadie tries to make sending HTML emails a little less painful (https://github.com/Mange/roadie)

group :test do

  gem 'turn', :require => false # Turn provides a set of alternative runners for MiniTest, both colorful and informative (http://github.com/TwP/turn)
end

group :development do
  gem 'rails-dev-tweaks', '~> 0.6.1'
  #gem 'jazz_hands', '~> 0.5.1'
  #gem 'binding_of_caller', "0.6.7"
  #gem "better_errors", "0.3.0"           # Provides a better error page for Rails and other Rack apps. (https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors)
  gem 'letter_opener'
end


#gem 'thin'
gem "cancan", "~> 1.6.7"

gem "whenever", :require => false
gem "delayed_job_active_record", "0.3.3"
gem "daemons", "1.1.9"
gem "prawn", '1.0.0.rc1'
gem "pdfkit", "~> 0.5.4"
gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary", "~> 0.9.9.1"
gem "cocaine", "0.3.2"
gem "rubyzip"
gem 'net-ssh', '2.7.0'

gem 'newrelic_rpm'

#Gem Json Parser
gem "json"

#Gem mailchip
gem "hominid"

#Gem Mailjet
gem "mailjet"

#Gem Utf8 invalid caracter cleaner
gem 'utf8-cleaner'

#Para paginación
gem "kaminari", "0.15.0"

gem 'dalli'

gem 'roo'
gem "spreadsheet", "~> 0.9.7"
gem 'sendgrid-rails', '~> 2.0'
gem 'color'
```

**Application.js.erb**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require_directory .
//
//= require mustache
//= require qTip/jquery.qtip
//= require plugin/jquery.metadata
//= require plugin/jquery.inputhintoverlay
//= require video/projekktor.min
//= require plugin/jquery.jmp3
//= require plugin/jquery.fancybox.pack
//= require plugin/jquery.fancybox-buttons
//= require plugin/jquery.fancybox-thumbs
//= require plugin/jquery.blockUI
//= require plugin/jquery.notify.min
//= require plugin/jquery.mousewheel
//= require perfectScrollbar/perfect-scrollbar
```

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: The `//=` parts are known as [Sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails) directives. Your Gemfile does not list sprockets and I don't remember if Rails 3.1 even shipped with sprockets. I would make a real priority of upgrading Rails & Ruby asap. Those are really old and insecure versions.

Comment: I guess Rails 3.1 introduced the sprockets asset pipeline, I'm guessing that this app was not properly updated to 3.1 though. You might want to dig through the release notes and try to find an update guide or skip straight to Rails 4.

Comment: I instaled sprockets into my gemfile but the problem remain the same. In fact, it's strange becuase we have three more machines running with this app in locale, but in the newest (an i5) the appication.js sprockets don't load xD